# Copy trait and PhantomData: Should this really move?

Tags: rust

`PhantomData` interacts with `Copy` in a surprising way:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Seconds;

pub struct Meters;

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Val<T> {
    pub v: PhantomData<T>
}

fn main() {
    let v1: Val<Seconds> = Val {v: PhantomData};
    let v2 = v1;
    let v3 = v1;

    let v4: Val<Meters> = Val {v: PhantomData};
    let v5 = v4;
    let v6 = v4;
}
```

This fails as follows:

```
src/main.rs:20:13: 20:15 error: use of moved value: `v4` [E0382]
src/main.rs:20         let v6 = v4;
                           ^~
src/main.rs:19:13: 19:15 note: `v4` moved here because it has type `Val<Meters>`, which is moved by default
src/main.rs:19         let v5 = v4;
```

I'd thought that deriving `Copy` for `Val<Meters>` would give `Val<Meters>` copy semantics. But apparently, that's true only where `Val`'s type parameter `T` also implements `Copy`. I don't understand why.

`PhantomData` always implements `Copy`, [regardless of whether its type parameter does](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html). And anyhow, if `PhantomData<Meters>` didn't implement `Copy`, I'd expect the compiler to complain that it couldn't derive `Copy` for `Val<Meters>`. Instead, the compiler happily derives `Copy` for `Val<Meters>`, yet it applies move semantics.

Is this behavior intentional? If so, why?

Answer (score 10):

> I'd thought that deriving Copy for `Val<Meters>` would give `Val<Meters>` copy semantics.

But `Copy` isn't being derived for `Val<Meters>`, just for all `Val<T>` where `T` itself is `Copy`.

There are several open issues on Github for this, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26925). My impression is that this is not intentional, but just a limitation of the way `derive` currently works.

You can work around this by manually writing a blanket impl for `Clone` and `Copy`:

```
impl <T> Clone for Val<T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Val<T> {
        Val {v: PhantomData}
    }
}

impl <T> Copy for Val<T> {}
```

Comment: I have the same impression as well, as far as I know `derive` used on generics only attempts to implement the trait based on whether the generic parameters themselves already implement it. I suspect the underlying issue is that deciding whether implementing the trait is possible or not is actually quite complicated and therefore it just implements a best effort at the moment; note that you can easily move to a manual implementation when `derive` fails.

Comment: This is surprising: All of `Val`'s fields are guaranteed to implement `Copy`, regardless of the type of `T` because `PhantomData` always implements `Copy`. Equally strange (but consistent with your remarks) is that `impl<T> Copy for Val<T>` fails because the compiler can't guarantee that `T` implements `Copy`. It seems like that shouldn't matter: The [docs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) say that "A type can implement `Copy` if all of its components implement `Copy`." The docs don't say that all the *type parameters* must also implement `Copy`.

Comment: @rlkw1024 Yeah, the whole situation is not ideal. There are fixmes like [this one](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcollections/linked_list.rs#L66) throughout the standard library. I'm not sure if this is an actual practical problem for you, but I've updated my answer to show how you can manually implement `Copy` for your type.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `PhantomData`, a field with type `&'a T` would fail the same way. It's about how deriving handles type parameters.